# Using Namespaces within Class Methods in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, oop, namespaces, traits

I would prefer to create a class that can handle AWS PHP SDK calls rather than having to set it up inline as needed. Given this example:

```
require('aws.phar');

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$region = 'us-east-1';

try {
 $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
  'credentials' => array(
   'key' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
   'secret' => AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY),
  'region' => $region,
  'version' => 'latest'
 ));

 print_r($s3->listBuckets());

}
catch (S3Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
catch (AwsException $e) {echo $e->getAwsErrorType().' '.$e->getAwsErrorCode();}
catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Ultimately, I'd like to have a class file like this (closest guess):

```
require_once('aws.phar');

class S3 {

 private $region = 'us-east-1';
 private $s3;

 public function create() {
  try {
   $this->s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
     'key' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
     'secret'   => AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY),
    'region' => $this->region,
    'version' => 'latest'
   ));
  }
  catch (Aws\Exception\AwsException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
  catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {echo $e->getAwsErrorType().' '.$e->getAwsErrorCode();}
  catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
 }

 public function list() {
  if (!$this->s3) return false;

  return $this->s3->listBuckets();
 }

}

$s3 = new S3();
$s3->create();
$s3->list();
```

I've looked for a solution, but I'm not getting anywhere. What I think was closest was using Traits, but then again, I've not used them before, so I didn't have any luck.

**--- Edit to add:**

I didn't note what was happening errorwise, but some of my initial errors disappeared after creating this example. I wasn't sure how the scope would work with having the `require_once` on the outside of the class and tried various things as I thought the class wouldn't be able to see the AWS namespaces. That clearly isn't the case as I'm able to run my test script, but it returns:

```
Unable to open phar://<path_omitted>/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Resources/s3-latest.php for reading
```

It executes up to `$this->s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory` and catches a standard `Exception` and displays the error message.

Comment: On the surface your example looks fine. Please add some information on 'I'm not getting anywhere' and 'I didn't have any luck'. Symptoms of the problem are important.

Comment: So... what's going wrong?

Comment: Oddly in cleaning it up, it is working better, but now saying: "Unable to open phar://<path_omitted>/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Resources/s3-latest.php for reading"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it turns out this works perfectly when I upload it to the server, but when testing within the IDE (Zend Studio/Eclipse), it was trying to access via a complete file path and that file path triggered a permission error.

I suspect there is some issues with permissions and phar packages with Zend/Eclipse. I'm not sure of a solution for making it work within the IDE, though.

---

Edited a year later to add a thorough answer:

Replacing the phar with the zipped files version (unzipped) works perfectly with Zend Studio. You can use the AWS `autoloader.php` file, but if you don't want a conflict with your own autoloader using `spl_autoload_register`, I suggest creating a copy of the file which removes their autoloader:

I placed a file called `aws_init.php` in the same folder as the `aws-autoloader.php` with their autoloader stripped out:

```
require __DIR__ . '/Aws/functions.php';
require __DIR__ . '/GuzzleHttp/functions_include.php';
require __DIR__ . '/GuzzleHttp/Psr7/functions_include.php';
require __DIR__ . '/GuzzleHttp/Promise/functions_include.php';
require __DIR__ . '/JmesPath/JmesPath.php';
```

In place of calling `aws-autoloader.php`, just call this new stripped down version `aws_init.php` to ensure all the functions are loaded.

For an autoloader, I'm using the following:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
 if (strpos($class_name,'\\') !== false) $class_name = str_replace('\\','/',$class_name);
 if (file_exists('inc/classes/'.$class_name.'.php')) {
  include('inc/classes/'.$class_name.'.php');
  return;
 }

 die('Unable to autoload class: inc/classes/'.$class_name);
});
```

This worked without needing any modification when I added in the AWS folders (`AWS`, `GuzzleHttp`, `Psr`, `JmesPath`) directly to the `classes` folder. Zend Studio is able to see these classes without issue in this set up.